# React / Redux Why is my animation not being triggered?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, gsap

I am using GSAP (greensock) to animate out my cards, I wrote this component initially with local mock data. With mock data, the animations were working as expected. However, since I started using live data from an endpoint, things have gone mysteriously wrong. I'm (obviously) not sure exactly where the problem is, but I have made some observations.

1. Data is making it into the map that is being used to attach the refs and ultimately animate the cards.
2. The callback at the end of the animation is triggering, so the whole thing is at least being executed.

If data is able to come in and be logged to console, plus the last step: the callback, is being called... Why is nothing appearing and animating on the dom?

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import TreasureCard from "../TreasureCard/TreasureCard";
import ActionCard from "../ActionCard/ActionCard";
import Card from "../Card/Card";
import { TimelineMax } from "gsap";
import { gsapCardsCycleIn } from "../../greenSock/animations";
import { mockPlayerData } from "../../mockData";
import "./PlayerHand.scss";

export class PlayerHand extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.cards = [];
    this.tl = new TimelineMax({ paused: true });
    this.state = { renderHand: false };
  }

  componentDidMount = () => {
    gsapCardsCycleIn(this.tl, this.cards, this.showUserHand);
  };

  showUserHand = () => {
    this.setState({ renderHand: true });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
       // -- this is the section that is not working correctly
        <section className='hand-animations'>
          {this.props.playerHand.length &&
            this.props.playerHand.map((card, i) => {
             // !! this console.log is successfully logging the appropriate expected data.
              console.log(card);
              return (
                <div className='animated-card' key={i} ref={div => (this.cards[i] = div)}>
                  <p>{card.name}</p>
                </div>
              );
            })}
        </section>
        <button onClick={() => this.tl.play()}>Start</button>
        <button onClick={() => this.tl.reverse()}>Reverse</button>
        <button onClick={() => this.tl.restart()}>Restart</button>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  playerHand: state.playerHand
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(PlayerHand);
```

Comment: is `playerHand` available at the beginning or is it async?

Comment: @Deryck I put a console.log() inside of the componentDidMount and it is indeed an empty array at mount time. Perhaps that's the issue?

Comment: yeah that would be it cuz that means you're just passing the empty `this.cards = []` into your `gsapCardsCycleIn(...)`

Comment: @Deryck yeah, i was thinking about that ... guess ill have to give componentDidUpdate a go

Comment: I think the issue is you are not getting an array from API call, you might be getting object. No need to use `componentDidUpdate` as you are directly using `this.props.playerHand`. You can check if you are getting an array or not in your `render` function. Try to put `console.log(this.props.playerHand)` in render function and you will see the data is an array/ object.

Comment: @ravibagul91 i have been rebuilding it with componentDidUpdate, i havent used that lifecycle method a lot in the past so im still getting used to it. It's very easy to infinite loop it unfortunately

Comment: As I already mention you don't need `componentDidUpdate` here. `componentDidUpdate` causing infinite loop, because it need's to be in a condition.

Comment: This [has been answered](https://greensock.com/forums/topic/21344-how-to-animate-async-data-react-redux/?tab=comments#comment-100423) over on the GSAP forums.